If $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h},$ why isn't $(g \circ f)'(x)= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{g(f(x)+h) - g(f(x))}{h}$?
In the proof of the Chain Rule, the author of my textbook starts with $ (g \circ f)'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{g(f(x+h)) - g(f(x))}{h}$.
My question is, if $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h},$ then why isn't it that $(g \circ f)'(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{g(f(x)+h) - g(f(x))}{h}$?

@MartinR Oops my bad! I'm fixing it now!

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(f(x)+h) - g(f(x))}{h}$ is equal to $g'(f(x))$. Why do you think it is equal to $(g \circ f)'(x)$?

@MartinR Yes, on your previous comment, I realized that my previous version of the term is $g'(f(x))$. However, I guess I'm still confused about why $(g \circ f)'(x)$ is defined as stated. What's the reason for it?

Set $F = g \circ f$ and write down the definition of $F'(x)$. Note that $F(x+h) = g(f(x+h))$.

@MartinR Yup! I think I got it now! Thank you very much!

$$
(g \circ f)'(x)= \lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{(g\circ f)(x+h) - (g \circ f)(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{g(f(x+h)) - g(f(x))}{h}
$$

Thank you very much!

Let $u=g\circ f$ , so then $u'(x)=(g \circ f)'(x)$. Now apply the limit definition on u,
$$\begin{align}
u'(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{u(x+h) - u(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(f(x+h)) - g(f(x))}{h}
\end{align}$$

Use \circ for the composition, that looks a bit nicer :)

Thank you very much!
